# trigger in MYSQL CONSOLE

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, console, phpmyadmin

I am working on `phpmyadmin`.
To write triggers i am using `mysql console`.
Its works well in starting. but as soon as i am writing a trigger and its gets execute successfully then every time after any query i have to give `delimiter` (|) to execute the query.
I am not able to understand why i have to put delimiter after a simple select query? Delimiter is for trigger rite.
Am i missing something in writing trigger?
for exmp:

after a trigger i am writing select statement than i have to write it as:

```
select * from tableName;|
```

If i am not using `|` its not getting execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `myTriggerName`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `myTriggerName` AFTER DELETE ON `myTableName` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

...........
............
.............

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

After the trigger is created, you need to change the delimiter back to ';'

See examples in the manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-defining.html

```
delimiter //

... your trigger here ...

delimiter ; <-- change the delimiter back
```